# Vaadin 14 Notification is stealing component from parent

Tags: java, components, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

i have very weird bug that is very easy to reproduce. I'm creating notification without duration with some components in it. It is opened in route layout with @PreserveOnRefresh. and after loading page everything is looking correctly but after i refresh browser tab then first component from page layout replaced layout inside notification. If I'm creating notification only with label like notification.setText("notif") without additional components then everything is working fine.

My Vaadin version: 14.8.14

Why is this happening? Is that how it should work?

Example code:

```
    @PreserveOnRefresh
@Route("test")
public class TestPanel  extends  Div{
    public TestPanel() {
        TextField username = new TextField("username");
        PasswordField password = new PasswordField("password");
        password.setPlaceholder("password");
        VerticalLayout mainVerticalLayout = new VerticalLayout(username,password);
        add(mainVerticalLayout);

        Notification notification = new Notification();
        notification.setDuration(0);
        HorizontalLayout notifLay = new HorizontalLayout(new Text("zalakladka"),new Button("btn"));
        notification.add(notifLay);
        notification.open();
    }
}
```

How the page looks at the beginning:

[image: How the page looks at the beginning]

How the page looks after refresh:

[image: How the page looks after refresh]

If i add my mainVerticalLayout inside another layout and add this new layout to page then
whole mainVerticalLayout will be added to notification layout.

```
VerticalLayout mainVerticalLayout = new VerticalLayout(username,password);
    VerticalLayout firstlayout = new VerticalLayout(mainVerticalLayout);
    add(firstlayout);
```

How the page looks after refresh:

[image]

Comment: That's a bug in the component when using @PreserveOnRefresh that has been fixed in newer versions: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/pull/3913. The fix has not been ported to v14.

Comment: so with older ver i will need to live with this bug?

Comment: You can create an issue in the repository linked above and ask for a back-port. Please do mention the original issue and pull request when doing so.